# PHP Parsing of German Date

Tags: php, date

I have a question about my code below. How can I format a German Date, for example "Di, 02.Okt 2012" to "2012-10-02"?

I already checked many sites for a solution but did not found something which could help me.

```
    $value ='Di, 02.Okt 2012';
    $tempdate = $value;
    $tempdate = substr($tempdate,-11);
    $tempdate = date('Y-m-d',$tempdate);
```

Output: 1970-01-01

Solved:

```
$value = 'comes from a foreach loop'; 

$tempdate = $value;
    $tempdate = substr($tempdate,-11);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Jan ', '-01-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Feb ', '-02-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Mär ', '-03-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Apr ', '-04-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Mai ', '-05-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Jun ', '-06-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Jul ', '-07-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Aug ', '-08-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Sep ', '-09-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Okt ', '-10-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Nov ', '-11-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = str_replace('.Dez ', '-12-', $tempdate);
    $tempdate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($tempdate));

    echo $tempdate.'<br/>';
```

This is the solution for many Dates. ^^ i hope i can help with it

Comment: have you tried to cast using `strtotime` before you format with `date`?

Comment: what language is that `Di, 02.Okt 2012`

Comment: @ranjith **"*How can i format German Date*"**

Comment: @tiger that one is close but doesn't include the day of the week *and* it doesn't have a **solution** which would not help the OP, yo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for your example.
When u have another date, replace "Okt" with another month and "-10-" with the number of the month.

```
$tempdate = 'Di, 02.Okt 2012';
$tempdate = str_replace('Di,', '', $tempdate);
$tempdate = str_replace('.Okt ', '-10-', $tempdate);
$tempdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($tempdate));
echo $tempdate;

// output: "2012-10-02"
```

Comment: Let's hope it's a *Tuesday in Oktober* ;)

Comment: yeah if the day changes, he has to change Di too of course :)

Comment: nice but i have not only this one Date so i have to make a Replace for all Mounts ^^

Comment: I would make $tempdate = substr($tempdate,-11); than $tempdate = str_replace('Di,', '', $tempdate); because ist for all new Verables

Answer (score 5):

Passing the `$date_string` variable containing **German days and months** in it to a function that uses [strtr (string translate)](http://php.net/strtr) along with an array of German days (and Months) will allow [**strtotime** (string to unix timestamp)](http://php.net/strtotime) to properly parse:

> [any **English** textual datetime description](http://php.net/strtotime)

Because [strtotime (string to unix timestamp)](http://php.net/strtotime) only parses English, manual intervention to translate those strings is necessary without [Internationalization](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php).

```
function germanStrtotime($date_string) {
  $germanDays = array('montag'=>'monday', 'mo'=>'monday', 'dienstag'=>'tuesday', 'di'=>'tuesday', 'mittwoch'=>'wednesday', 'mi'=>'wednesday', 'donnerstag'=>'thursday', 'do'=>'thursday', 'freitag'=>'friday', 'fr'=>'friday', 'samstag'=>'saturday', 'sa'=>'saturday', 'sonntag'=>'sunday', 'so'=>'sunday');
  $germanMonths = array('jnuar'=>'january', 'jan'=>'january', 'jän'=>'january', 'februar'=>'february', 'feb'=>'february', 'marz'=>'march', 'märz'=>'march', 'mai'=>'may', 'juni'=>'june', 'oktober'=>'october', 'okt'=>'october', 'sept'=>'september', 'dezember'=>'december', 'dez'=>'december');
  $str = strtr(strtolower($date_string), $germanMonths);
  $str = strtr(strtolower($str), $germanDays);
  return strtotime($str);
}

$value ='Di, 02.Okt 2012';
$tempdate = $value;
$tempdate = germanStrtotime($tempdate);
$tempdate = date('Y-m-d', $tempdate);

die('Output: '.$tempdate); // 2012-10-02
```

Comment: Thats a good one too :)

Comment: Thx man ^^ i got this now aleady :D

Answer (score 1):

For internationalization tasks, I'd strongly recommend using the PHP [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension. It contains several classes for common internationalization tasks such as date/time formatting, number formatting, string transliteration and more. Specifically, the [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class is able to format (and parse) a datetime for any available locale.